# How to erase an old result when clicking on a wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a wxPython script, which executes a process after clicking the button and display the process output in a wx.StaticText. 
The problem is when I want to re-execute the process , and so I click on button and the old result is displayed (output of the first process); this old result is still displayed on the window, while I have added an instruction that normally will hide it:

Here is lines of my code:

```
def OnButton(self, e):
    if self.res=="udpscan":
        self.resultat1.SetLabel("")
        ipad=self.ipadd.GetValue()
        fromm=self.fr.GetValue()
        too=self.to.GetValue()
        ifc=self.intf.GetValue()
        if len(ipad) <1  or len(too) < 1 or len(fromm) <1 or len(ifc) < 1:
            wx.MessageBox('Please enter missing values','error',wx.OK)
        else:
            sp=subprocess.Popen(['python','udp_portscan.py',ifc,ipad,fromm,too],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            text=sp.stdout.readlines()
            text="".join(text)
            self.resultat1.SetLabel(text)
```

I have tried to add other intructions to hide it but same problem. 
Can you help me please. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

sp seems to store all the previous output in sp.stdout.

There might be a way to clear it using .kill():

```
      sp=subprocess.Popen(['python','udp_portscan.py',ifc,ipad,fromm,too],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
      text=sp.stdout.readlines()
      sp.kill()
```